# kubernetes dashboard: square/go-jose: error in cryptographic primitive

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to make a CI/CD job on Gitlab that on commit will install a helm chart on a kubernetes cluster on google cloud. The only way i found how to do this was to copy the contents of the kube config file and paste it in a location inside my runner (that does not have the gcloud sdk), but then i realised that the token that gcloud would generate inside the config file would change periodically, so i looked for another solution and I found the application default credentials. I don't really understand the gcloud application-default set of commands tho, i ran login (on my local machine which has gcloud sdk) and it generated a json file with some credentials inside. Then i set the CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_USE_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS env var to true and then I copied this file, and the re-generated config file inside the runner, and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env to point to the file and it works. Im not quite sure why, tho.

What does gcloud application-default login actually do? I mean before doing this i didnt have the json file, and everytime i would run gcloud cluster get-credentials to switch between clusters i would see an access-token for each context that i could use to login on the dashboard, but after i did this on my local machine, sometimes the dashboard gives me a weird error: square/go-jose: error in cryptographic primitive.

Do you have any idea what im doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would say GCP documentation explains pretty well what application-default auth does:

> Obtains user access credentials via a web flow and puts them in the
>   well-known location for Application Default Credentials to use them as
>   a proxy for a service account. This command is useful when you are
>   developing code that would normally use a service account but need to
>   run the code in a local development environment where it's easier to
>   provide user credentials.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#calling) you will find more details and some examples about the subject.

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to a bad token (you switched your clusters contexts while logged in to the kubernetes dashboard)

If you sign out from the dashboard and sign in again, the error should disappear.